# How to find where permission request goes

Tags: office-365, access, check-permissions

Using Office 365 SharePoint. We have a site called "legal". Our new secretary needs to access it but nobody knows who it is sending the access request to.

How can I find the user that gets the "Secretary would like to access Legal SharePoint" message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These requests usually get emailed to the Site Owners group members.

You can check by going to the Site Settings page for the site and there clicking Site Permissions. There click Access Request Settings.

[image]

[image]